# Low slope in Added variable plots indicative of what?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization, scatterplot

I have 8 predictors and for 4 of them, the AV plots have a slope close to 0. Is that enough information for me to leave out these predictors in my model?

Answer (score 1):

If there's not otherwise pattern (such as a nonlinear trend), lack of slope in an added-variable plot would tend to indicate that the variable wouldn't help you explain the response over what was in the model.

However, note that this is still a form of model selection, and will have a similar effect on your inferences* that other forms of stepwise selection would have.

* (on test significance levels, confidence interval coverage, bias of estimates and standard errors and so on)

Comment: Thank you for responding. So if I'm understanding you correctly, a model that excludes the predictors that had near zero slopes in its AV plot should be compared to other models generated using, for example, stepwise regression?

Comment: Definitely not saying that. I'm pointing out that variable selection in whatever form, when done on the same data as you're using for your hypothesis tests, confidence intervals, predictions etc has an impact on the properties of those procedures -- they no longer behave "as advertised". If you don't have to do selection (e.g. if you can reasonably include all your variables, which is sometimes true) then that's a way to avoid the problem; or if you need to do selection, there are ways to go about it (but they cost you something in effective sample size).

Comment: If you'd add a variable that showed a strong relationship in the AV plot, and would avoid adding it if it did not, you're doing variable selection. If you redo AV plots after you add a variable, you're doing stepwise selection (specifically, forward selection) -- if less formally; the impact will be the same.

Comment: In regression analysis, is what I'm doing (variable selection) appropriate? I am also planning on using stepwise selection, so I suppose I should skip variable selection if it's redundant and less formal?

Comment: "Appropriate" is a tricky word. I'm not saying "don't do variable selection". I'm saying that if you *do* do it, you will incur some costs and you have some control over the kinds of costs you'll pay and how big they might be. If you do it in some ways the costs are mostly hidden and potentially severe; if you do it in other ways the costs are up front and usually modest. There are many questions on this issue. .... as to whether there's a particular problem with both looking at AV plots and doing variable selection more formally, I don't see any additional issue.

Comment: If you're not using AV plots to choose whether to add a variable but more as a diagnostic (e.g. to see how confident you should be about the model you had, that's different)

Comment: I was actually thinking of making one model from just looking at AV plots and other models using stepwise and then using ANOVA to find the better model.

Comment: ... which is simply more model selection. I'd encourage you to borrow a copy of Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*, and read chapter 4 (at least it's chapter 4 in the first edition). The information it gives is mostly available elsewhere but it's a good place to find it and explains it pretty well. I'd also encourage you to read about sample splitting and [cross validation](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/crossvalidation/) (which our site is named after!). *Elements of Statistical Learning* (which you can find in pdf form on Tibshirani's web page) is one place of many to do that